# Using meshgrid to interpolate image's physical coordinates

Tags: matlab

I am new to Matlab and am simulating a physical phenomena that requires the physical coordinates of my image. For example I can use the following to give the dimensions of my image.

```
a = phantom(80,250) 
a(81:250,:) = [];
```

For my physical system, I need the spacing to be 2 between each pixel and for the object to go from 0:2:280 in x and 0:2:410 in y. I am trying to use meshgrid to see if it will help the case by starting with

```
[x,y] = meshgrid(1:1:100, 1:1:300);
[xm,ym] = meshgrid(1:.5:300, 1:.5:450);

M = interp2(x,y,a,xm,ym,'nearest');
```

This does not give me what I want but is how I think I can potentially achieve a solution.

My basic problem is I have the image which is size (80,250) and I need to sample/scale it so that I can correlate a point on the top right as location (280mm,410mm) with a sample of 2mm between each pixel. Is this the right approach or should I use another function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, the image is **not** 80 x 250. Be sure to go checkout the [documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/phantom.html).

What exactly are you hoping to do after this step? That really determines whether this is the appropriate way to go about this.

But based on your code and your last statement, you want the x range to be 0 - 280 and the y range to be 0 - 410.

```
xrange = linspace(0, 280, size(a, 2));
yrange = linspace(0, 410, size(a, 1));
```

So now your reference coordinates for your image would be

```
[xx,yy] = meshgrid(xrange, yrange);
```

Now how you want to sample that is really up to you. It sounds like you want every 2mm? So let's construct the grid to sample on.

```
[xq, yq] = meshgrid(0:2:max(xx(:)), 0:2:max(yy(:)));
```

Now we can actually do our interpolation. The important thing to remember is that the reference coordinates (`x` and `y`) **must** be the same size as your input image (`a`). This was one of the problems with your initial attempt.

```
M = interp2(x,y,a,xq,yq,'nearest');
```

Comment: what I am hoping to do is basically use the values of the image at that specific coordinate. For example the image could have the value of 1 at (280, 410) but the image in Matlab has it so that (80,250) has the value of 1. However, the coordinate (79,250) = 0 in the image and what would that correspond to in the "real" dimensions. Basically a coordinate transformation of sorts.

Comment: @curiousgeorge yea so in the above solutions you can change xq and yq to any point you want to query and that should work just fine.